# Two loading bars when looking at profile summary

Tags: bug

I am not sure if this is a bug, but I noticed a strange behavior today. If you find any high reputation Stack Overflow user, go to their Top/Newest All/Questions/Answers, and if both categories are struggling to load at the same time, you'll actually get two loading bars side-by-side (for a brief moment):

[image]

Typically you only get one loading bar directly to the left of "All" - it doesn't seem practical to have two loading bars side-by-side there (since they just do the same thing, they're exactly synchronized).

To reproduce, find a high reputation (I used [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) in my example) and select "Answers" and "Votes". Next, quickly change those to "All" and "Newest" - if your fast enough (or your computers slow enough) you might see two loading bars appear.

This was on Google Chrome version 71.0.3578.98 (official build) (64-bit).

Comment: This can easily be repro-ed in Chrome for any user by opening the developer tools, network pane, and setting throttling to the _slow 3G_ preset, you can even get 3 loading bars at the same time (without it I'm having a hard time repro-ing this). Though I'm unsure if it's an actual bug, since the page is in fact loading multiple pages